# prevent user to login from other device or other browser at same time

Tags: php, mysql

prevent user to login from other device or other browser at same time
If user is logged in from one pc/device then that perticular user can not log in using same id and password from another pc/device or another browser.

using php and mysql

Comment: 1) You shouldn't need to do this.  2) If you insist on doing this, what have you tried?  I imagine you'd just have to store somewhere the fact that the user is logged in.  Then when someone tries to login, check that value.

Comment: And you expect us to write all the code for you? [Please put more effort into your question.](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints)

Comment: Is that just a statement? Or do you ave any questions ...?

Comment: OP is just telling us what he's been doing today.

Comment: i have tried to save the user is logged in. but when user is just closing the browser instead of logout the problem is how to reset / change the user logged in is false/no.??

Comment: Use Session IDs and add an activity timeout to the sessions

Comment: can you please write me the code for use session ids and activity timeout to the session?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330478/how-to-prevent-concurrent-user-logins-in-php-mysql-site?rq=1

Comment: @Ritesh: That's precisely one of the biggest reasons why you *shouldn't* do this.  You have no reliable mechanism of knowing whether the user has logged out.  You're going to have to track all user actions and keep a running timestamp of the last logged-in action, then define some acceptable length of time after which you would *assume* a user has logged out.  During that length of time, though, the user still will be arbitrarily denied access.  You really, really shouldn't do this unless you're int he habit of annoying your users.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a separate column in your db table e.g. is_logged and when a user is logged for first time it will be updated to true so every other attempt will fail.

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE username = 'username' AND password = 'password' AND is_logged != 1;
```

UPDATE (based on your update)

You can have another column such as last_action (timestamp) and set in your application logic a particular time that if a user hasn't interact with the website (e.g. 3600 seconds) then he will be considered as automatically logged out during his next login attempt.

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE username = 'username' AND password = 'password' 
AND TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), last_action)) > 3600;
```

Comment: It would be nice to explain the downvote.

Comment: Your initial answer did not account for a user that does not log out manually thus the high probability of a user being locked out from a previous session that did not clear.

Comment: Yes, but OP didn't clarified it at his question at all. After his comment i updated my answer accordingly. Still, it's not the perfect solution but a solution that can work for his particular question so i really believe this downvote is a bit unfair.

Comment: application logic a particular time that if a user hasn't interact with websites. how can this be done?

Comment: I think that the last_action method can solve this. If the user hasn't interact with the application for the last 1440 seconds then at his next click inside the website the check above will fail and he will be redirected to logout action.

Comment: Otherwise you can solve this using a cron_job that it will scan e.g. 'user' table checking for users that don't have interact with the application.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a column in your login table( besides where you have stored password and username) and set it to one whenever a user logs in. Check that column every time with password and username. If it is not one. Grant login. else  error message. Set it to zero when a user logs out.